# R Scraping for image details from several thousand pages

Tags: r, web, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape details from a website in order to gather details for pictures with a script in R.

What I need is:

- Image name (1.jpg)
- Image caption ("A recruit demonstrates the proper use of a CO2 portable extinguisher to put out a small outside fire.")
- Photo credit ("Photo courtesy of: James Fortner")

There are over 16,000 files, and thankfully the web url goes "...asp?photo=1, 2, 3, 4" so there is base url which doesn't change, just the last section with the image number. I would like the script to loop for either a set number (I tell it where to start) or it just breaks when it gets to a page which doesn't exisit.

Using the code below, I can get the caption of the photo, but only one line. I would like to get the photo credit, which is on a separate line; there are three 
 between the main caption and photo credit. I'd be fine if the table which is generated had two or three blank columns to account for the 
 lines, as I can delete them later.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

link = "http://fallschurchvfd.org/photovideo.asp?photo=1"
page = read_html(link)

caption = page %>% html_nodes(".text7 i") %>% html_text()

info = data.frame(caption, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
write.csv(info, "photos.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

For the images, you can use the command line tool `curl`. For example, to download images `1.jpg` through `100.jpg`

```
curl -O "http://fallschurchvfd.org/photos/[0-100].jpg"
```

For the `R` code, if you grab the whole `.text7` section, then you can split into caption and photo credit subsequently:

```
extractedtext <- page %>% html_nodes(".text7") %>% html_text()
caption <- str_split(extractedtext, "\r\n\t\t\t\t")[[1]][1]
credit <- str_split(extractedtext, "\r\n\t\t\t\t")[[1]][3]
```

As a loop

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

df<-data.frame(id=1:20, 
               image=NA,
               caption=NA,
               credit=NA)
for (i in 1:20){
  cat(i, " ") # to monitor progress and debug
  link <- paste0("http://fallschurchvfd.org/photovideo.asp?photo=", i)
  tryCatch({ # This is to avoid stopping on an error message for missing pages
            page <- read_html(link)
            close(link)
            df$image[i] <- page %>% html_nodes(".text7 img") %>% html_attr("src")
            extractedtext <- page %>% html_nodes(".text7") %>% html_text()
            df$caption[i] <- str_split(extractedtext, "\r\n\t\t\t\t")[[1]][1] # This is an awkward way of saying "list 1, element 1"
            df$credit[i] <- str_split(extractedtext, "\r\n\t\t\t\t")[[1]][3]
            }, 
           error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
}
```

I get inconsistent results with this current code, for example, page 15 has more line breaks than page 1.

TODO: enhance string extraction; switch to an 'append' method of adding data to a data.frame (vs pre-allocate and insert).

Answer (score 0):

Scraping with `rvest` and `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

get_picture <- function(page) {
  cat("Scraping page", page, "\n")
  
  page <- str_c("http://fallschurchvfd.org/photovideo.asp?photo=", page) %>%
    read_html()
  
  tibble(
    image_name = page %>%  
      html_element(".text7 img") %>%
      html_attr("src"),
    caption = page %>%
      html_element(".text7") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      str_split(pattern = "\r\n\t\t\t\t") %>%
      unlist %>% 
      nth(1),
    credit = page %>%
      html_element(".text7") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      str_split(pattern = "\r\n\t\t\t\t") %>%
      unlist %>% 
      nth(3)
  )
}

# Get the first 1:50 
df <- map_dfr(1:50, possibly(get_picture, otherwise = tibble()))

# A tibble: 42 × 3
   image_name     caption                                   credit
   <chr>          <chr>                                     <chr> 
 1 /photos/1.jpg  Recruit Clay Hamric demonstrates the use… James…
 2 /photos/2.jpg  A recruit demonstrates the proper use of… James…
 3 /photos/3.jpg  Recruit Paul Melnick demonstrates the pr… James…
 4 /photos/4.jpg  Rescue 104                                James…
 5 /photos/5.jpg  Rescue 104                                James…
 6 /photos/6.jpg  Rescue 104                                James…
 7 /photos/15.jpg Truck 106 operates a ladder pipe from Wi… Jim O…
 8 /photos/16.jpg Truck 106 operates a ladder pipe as heav… Jim O…
 9 /photos/17.jpg Heavy fire vents from the roof area of t… Jim O…
10 /photos/18.jpg Arlington County Fire and Rescue Associa… James…
# … with 32 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: I was looking for a function like `nth()`!